# Select From one table : single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to select some data from one table using a subquery, the main objectif is to select the last occurrence of each ID (the last ligne = the max NULIGN), so I used:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE NULIGN= (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(NULIGN) FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY ID);
```

I got the following error:

> single-row subquery returns more than one row.

So how can I display all the occurrence with the max ligne number?

Comment: Replace = with in?

Comment: Yes I tried but it selects all the rows , not only the last occurrences of each ID

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result! (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Don't use `group by ID`. The actual subquery will return one row per ID.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Using distinct with group by is pointless. Drop distinct.

Comment: I have recently seen a similar query using IN in mysql where the outer query appeared to coerce the invalid(ie incorrect use of group by) sub query into selecting all rows. It would be interesting if you could provide sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alternative you could use join

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM TABLE1 a
JOIN( SELECT ID,MAX(NULIGN) MAX_NULIGN
      FROM TABLE1 
      GROUP BY ID
) b
ON a.ID = b.ID
AND a.NULIGN= b.MAX_NULIGN;
```

Or make your sub query as correlated sub query

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 a
WHERE a.NULIGN= (SELECT MAX(NULIGN) 
                 FROM TABLE1 
                WHERE ID = a.ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your subsquery return more than a row (based on group by id)  so you need a IN clause

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE NULIGN IN  (
    SELECT DISTINCT MAX(NULIGN) 
    FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY ID);
```

or you can do the same with a join

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(NULIGN) max_nulign
      FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY ID) T ON T.max_nulign = TABLE1.NULIGN ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the = and use IN operator

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE NULIGN IN (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(NULIGN) FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY ID);
```

Because when you use =, the operator is expecting to only 1 value on the RHS. So if  you want to give a group of values, Use IN